# Elasticsearch high level REST client - Indexing has latency

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient, elasticsearch-rest-client

we have started using the high level REST client finally, to ease the development of queries from backend engineering perspective. For indexing, we are using the `client.update(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)` so that new documents will be created and existing ones modified.

The issue that we are seeing is, the indexing is delayed, almost by 5 minutes. I see that they use async http calls internally. But that should not take so long, I looked for some timing options inside the library, didn't find anything. Am I missing anything or the official documentation is missing for this?

Comment: Does your index have a different `refresh_interval` set up than the default one (i.e. 1 second)?

Comment: This index has "refresh_interval":"-1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `refresh_interval: 1` in your index settings, it means it is never [refreshed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) unless you do it manually, which is why you don't see the data just after it's been updated.

You have three options here:

A. You can call the `_update` endpoint with the `refresh=true` (or `refresh=wait_for`) parameter to make sure that the index is refreshed just after your update.

B. You can simply set `refresh_interval: 1s` (or any other duration that makes sense for you) in your index settings, to make sure the index is automatically refreshed on a regular basis.

C. You can explicitly [call `index/_refresh`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) on your index to refresh it whenever you think is appropriate.

Option B is the one that usually makes sense in most use cases.

Comment: Yeah, setting the refresh_interval to 1s helped, I can see the updates immediately now.

Answer (score 0):

Several reference on using the refresh `wait_for` but I had a hard time finding what exactly needed to be done in the rest high level client.
For all of you that are searching this answer:

```
   IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(index, DOC_TYPE, id);
   request.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL);
```