# ElasticSearch ReIndex Request not working in synchronous manner using Java Rest High Level Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I have 2 indexes with names -
`source_index`,
`destination_index`

Both indexes have same mappings.

I have written following code for making reindex and search requests -

```
@Autowired
RestHighLevelClient client;

public BulkByScrollResponse reIndexElasticResponse(ReindexRequest reindexRequest){
    BulkByScrollResponse reindexResponse = null;
    try{
      reindexResponse = client.reindex(reindexRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e){
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return reindexResponse;
}

public SearchResponse searchElasticResponseByScrollAPI(SearchScrollRequest searchScrollRequest) {
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
      searchResponse =  client.scroll(searchScrollRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return searchResponse;
}
```

Now my application is reindexing **only selected records** from `source_index` to `destination_index`.
And just after reindexing request, I am running one **search** query on `destination_index`.

The problem is that my search query is not giving me correct response as I think that reindexing request is not working in synchronous manner.
If I use `Thread.sleep(5000);` after my reindexing request then my search query gives me correct result.

```
reIndexElasticResponse(reindexRequest);
Thread.sleep(5000);
searchElasticResponseByScrollAPI(searchScrollRequest);
```

The above code will work fine. But if I comment `Thread.sleep(5000)` then search query doesn't give expected output.

**I want my program to wait until all the records are reindexed and then run the search query on** `destination_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour because it should be take some time to refresh index after commiting index (default is 1 second). You can read answer provided by Val [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66928354/5489276) which will give you more clarity why this is happening.

So when you are setting `Thread.sleep(5000);` in your code, elastic is able to complete index refresh so you are able to get search response.

Below code changes you can done in your code to refresh index manully.

```java
public BulkByScrollResponse reIndexElasticResponse(ReindexRequest reindexRequest){
    BulkByScrollResponse reindexResponse = null;
    try{
      reindexRequest.setRefresh(true); <--- check this one
      reindexResponse = client.reindex(reindexRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e){
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return reindexResponse;
}
```